# Trying to find pattern in an array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, pattern-matching

[0, 4, 13, 23, 16, 3, 0, -3, -11, -12, -5, -3, -2, 0, -3, -5]

I am trying to find if the integers in my array are increasing, decreasing, stays the same or does not follow any pattern (random).
 What is the efficient way to do this using python?

Comment: What is exact definition of pattern?

Comment: Without a concise definition, it will be very hard to provide a useful answer to your question. For example: how long must a pattern continue to be considered a "valid" pattern?

Comment: It does not have restrictions in terms of length. It can keep increasing, decreasing or there might not be any change at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.  "Can someone help me with this?" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

First check if all the values are the same. If not, sort a copy of it. If the copy is the same as the original, it's increasing. Reverse the copy. If they are the same it's decreasing. Otherwise it's random.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an idea:
Init 2 variables (inc, dec) as false.

Loop over the list with range(length(list)-1) and check if the current value is bigger or higher then the previous one. If value increases set inc to true (If dec set var dec to true).

After the iteration check which value is set to true. If only one value is true you know if it is dec / inc. If both are set to true you have some random order.

Please note, that you can even check during the iteration over the loop if dec/inc is set to true and If booth are alteady true you know you can stop the iteration (== random).